# Cascading dropdown menus with Ajax & Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a cascading dropdown system working using jquery and simple ajax script. I can get the first dropdown to work (pull values from database to fill select field) but on the second or subsequent, I can't get the ajax script to fire. Here is the code I am using. Any help would be appreciated

```
<select name="claiming_unit" id="claiming_unit" >
<option value="">Select Claiming Unit</option>
<option value="1">Claiming Unit 1</option>
<option value="2">Claiming Unit 2</option>
<option value="3">Claiming Unit 3</option>
</select>

<script>
    function makeAjaxRequest(opts){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                claimingunit: opts,
            },
            url: "/get_job_categories.pl",
            success: function(res) {
                $("#results").html(res);
            }
        });
    }
    $("#claiming_unit").on("change", function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        makeAjaxRequest(selected);
    });
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

This works, and my cgi script prints a new select and the ajax script to call another dropdown in the

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

This is what is prints:

```
<select name="job_category" id="job_category" >
<option value="">Select Job Category</option>
<option value="1">Job Category 1</option>
<option value="2">Job Category 2</option>
<option value="3">Job Category 3</option>
</select>
<script>
    function makeAjaxRequest2(opts){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                jobcategory: opts,
            },
            url: "/get_job_categories.pl",
            success: function(res) {
                $("#results2").html(res);
            }
        });
    }

    $("job_category").on("change", function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        makeAjaxRequest2(selected);
    });
</script>
<div id="results2"></div>
```

However, when I make a selection from this menu, it does not fire and get me the third select menu from the cgi script - nothing appears in the `<div id="results2"></div>`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: is `job_category`  appended dynamically  ?

Comment: Also , `$("job_category")` should be `$("#job_category")` if you select the `id`

Comment: This was the problem, simple code syntax issue. Thanks for your time. Sorry to waste it on a trivial issue.